# Angular / Jasmine Unit Testing - How Do You Test If A Function Was Called If Its $scope Element is Cleared Within the Tested Function?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a controller function that looks like:

```
$scope.clearMarkers = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.markers.length; i++){
        $scope.markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    $scope.markers = [];
};
```

My unit test for the above looks like:

```
describe('clearMarkers Test', function(){
    it('should call the setMap() method on each array object inside of scope.markers and then set scope.markers to an' +
       'empty array', function(){
        scope.markers = [{
            setMap: jasmine.createSpy('scope.markers[0]#setMap')
        }, {
            setMap: jasmine.createSpy('scope.markers[1]#setMap')
        }, {
            setMap: jasmine.createSpy('scope.markers[2]#setMap')
        }];
        scope.clearMarkers();
        expect(scope.markers[0].setMap).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null);
        expect(scope.markers[1].setMap).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null);
        expect(scope.markers[2].setMap).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null);
        expect(scope.markers).toEqual([]);
    });
});
```

The above test will error out when asserting that the `setMap()` methods should have been called because setting `$scope.markers = []` in `$scope.clearMarkers()` also deletes the spies I created.

If I comment out `$scope.markers = []` in `$scope.clearMarkers()` then my `setMap()` assertions work as expected.

How would I preserve my spies in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Spies should be object methods at the moment of call but they don't need to be object methods to be asserted:

```
var markerSpy1 = jasmine.createSpy();
...

scope.markers = [
  { setMap: markerSpy1 },
  ...
];

scope.clearMarkers();
expect(markerSpy1).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null);
...
expect(scope.markers).toEqual([]);
```

Comment: When you're downvoting a correct answer, please, explain your decision.

Comment: @LloydBanks The question was neglected and there was no feedback. Were the solutions helpful for you? If they did, consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, creating spys on actual function and checking if they are being called or not,

```
describe('clearMarkers Test', function(){
it('should call the setMap() method on each array object inside of scope.markers and then set scope.markers to an' +
   'empty array', function(){

   spyOn(scope.markers[0], 'setMap')// setting spy on this function
   spyOn(scope.markers[1], 'setMap')
   spyOn(scope.markers[2], 'setMap')
    scope.markers = [{
        setMap: jasmine.createSpy('scope.markers[0]#setMap')
    }, {
        setMap: jasmine.createSpy('scope.markers[1]#setMap')
    }, {
        setMap: jasmine.createSpy('scope.markers[2]#setMap')
    }];
    scope.clearMarkers();
    expect(scope.markers[0].setMap).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null);
    expect(scope.markers[1].setMap).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null);
    expect(scope.markers[2].setMap).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null);
    expect(scope.markers).toEqual([]);
});
```

});

if you want to call the spied function as well just use:

```
spyOn(scope.markers[0], 'setMap').and.callThrough()
```

Hope this solves your problem